# Formatting from IDE affects the displayed HTML Angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am faced with the problem when formatting code in IDE affected displayed HTML. Here is [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i9wecd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.html). As you can see there are spaces between names in second div.

The problem is that i want my code is formatted in the same form as in `div` with `class="second"`. But i don't want spaces in the HTML between names. I understand that spaces appear due to the line break between names. But is there a way to not showing spaces except make all the code in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel your pain. I've run into this problem many times.

You can remove the extra whitespace by setting the `font-size: 0` to the `.second` style, and then setting `font-size: 14px` to just the text.

https://angular-ldbx8q.stackblitz.io

You'll have to wrap the text in a `<span>` that should be formatted normally.

```
<div class="second">
    <span class="txt">Formatted code: </span>
    <ng-container *ngIf="isFirstNameAllowedToShow">
      <span class="txt">{{name1}}</span>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="isSecondNameAllowedToShow">
      <span class="txt">{{name2}}</span>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="isThirdNameAllowedToShow">
      <span class="txt">{{name3}}</span>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

This happens to me when I'm doing menus.

Comment: Thank you. So there is no way to fix this without such hacks?

Comment: @DenisYalomist not really, and I don't think it's a hack. It's been a known issue with HTML for many years. It's how HTML handles whitespace. The alternative is to disable formatting in your IDE and write everything on one line. So both solutions have drawbacks.